# MS Word Equation Accent with Dots

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, equation, formal-languages

Consider the following equation:

[image]

It's not readable because that the accent forces the `j` and `i` dots to disappear, while the `argmax` variable is i with its dot.
How can I force the dots to appear and still be able to use the triangle accent ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `normal text` button from `Equation Design -> Tools` fix that.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

At frist this is not a question for StackOverflow since this is not about programming.

The solution is to use a font which does not use [ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature).